# REST API Security using Signature, where/how to store secret key?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, security

I created a REST API and implemented a Signature system as a layer of security, basically how it works is that I have API users that connect to the API using a secret key(lets say a password) that only the user and the API know, then after a session is open the API return an API key to be used for all subsequent calls.

All subsequents call will provide the API key and a sha256 hash of the different request parameters, hash created using the secret key.

So far so good, however I am facing a problem where I have a full AJAX client calling the API, but I don't want my users to type their username and password(secret key) everytime they want to open a session and get a new API Key if they previously connected to the API in the past.

Temporarily, I am storing the secret key in plain text in a cookie using javascript but it seems wrong to me.

Do you guys have suggestions or links to point me too? Is there something I don't understand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them a hashed lease on the API. A lease grants them access to the API for a certain amount of time, and that time is specified in the token. For example, it could be good for the next 7 days. You can do this by simply adding the end date to your token and signing it.

When the app goes back to try and start a new session, it can ask the server to give it a new lease, assuming they're already authenticated, good for another 7 days.

If they try to access the server after 7 days, then they need to re-authenticate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is an interesting idea, however, if I understand correctly, the 7days expiry time could also mean a 7days window of local vulnerability assuming some token are stored on browser cookies?

Comment: I am still looking for more suggestions if anyone has any. ;)